# Why do AWT EventListeners duplicate event information in the method and the event itself

Tags: java, event-handling

In many of the standard Java libraries (and most notably in AWT/Swing) you can find the following EventListener / Event pattern:

```
 interface FooEventListener {
      void fooDidBar(FooEvent e);
      void fooDidBaz(FooEvent e);
      void fooDidQux(FooEvent e);
 }
```

And, in the `FooEvent`, you further find

```
 public class FooEvent {
      static int FOO_DID_BAR = 1;
      static int FOO_DID_BAZ = 2;
      static int FOO_DID_QUX = 3;
      // ...
      public int getID(); // one of the above constants
 }
```

This seems redundant. Why was this decision taken? What is the advantage of having this information both in the specific method called and in the event passed as an argument to that method?

Examples:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListDataListener.html

Comment: The core event dispatching process knows very little about the listener which might receive the event. In fact, the original API didn't have listeners, instead, you'd overrode the `processEvent` method and made your own determinations based on the event ID.  As an event is "pumped" to a component, it will make a determination about whether it can handle the event or not.  If it can, it will then determine how best it can dispatch the event to registered listeners, which would included determining the type of event (via the id) which is then sent to the correct method.

Comment: What you're seeing is an evolution of the API/system over time, with a focus on maintaining backwards compatibility.

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Are you saying that the event constants and the listener methods have been added to JDK not at the same time?

Comment: [Something like this](http://pawlan.com/monica/articles/jdk1.0/) and [this](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/javanotes3/c6/s7.html) might help better explain some of the reasoning

Comment: @MadProgrammer your first comment almost looks like a full answer. If converted into one would be happy to upvote it. The two links in your later comment also describe some of the old mechanism (I started using Java when Swing had already displaced AWT), but do not provide much information on the design perspective: why was it done so?

Comment: The original awt was written in a night (if I remember the story) and was written as a requirement from Netscape. I believe the intended api was more along the lines of Swing. It’s impossible to know extant “why” it was written the way it was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reasons are:

1) All AWT/Swing events extend `AWTEvent` and need to provide event id to its parent constructor. This is partly required by legacy AWT codebase and for event dispatching as mentioned by @MadProgrammer.

2) It is much cleaner design to implement one particular callback method in the listener instead of checking for event id constants in a single method. Actually in old days we would just delegate to private methods from a single event callback method based on event id.

3) This allowed the use of Adapter classes that help to only implement callback methods for only interested events.

Comment: Adapter classes generally provide empty handlers all events, so that subclasses can decide which ones to override. In this sense, I do not understand answer 3) - why are IDs useful when building adapter classes?

Comment: Can you give an example of "old-days private method delegation"? It is not immediately clear from reading 2)

Comment: The old days we would override `handleEvent` method and check for event id and call private method for that particular event (such `handleMouseEnter` or `handleWindowClose`) instead of implementing particular callback method. The mentioning of Adapter classes was in context of callback method. When AWT/Swing introduced callback interfaces developers started to complain that they had to provide empty implementation for all unrelated callback methods that cluttered the code. And Java team introduced the Adapter later.

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, I think I see additional advantages to double-encoding event subtypes (`Bar`, `Baz`, `Qux` in the example), beyond its historical importance:

- Having one callback-method per event subtype allows cleaner listener implementations, as no switch-like statements are needed to take different actions for each subtype. So far this is used in most event-handling code and is pretty evident.
- Having a subtype-id (`getId()`, which could be renamed to `getType()` for non-legacy events) in the event objects themselves is relatively low-cost from an implementation perspective (define a bunch of constants and keep them in sync with the corresponding subtype methods); and when present allows interesting debugging strategies: the sequence of events fired by a particular model can then contain all the information needed to reconstruct all changes to the model. Essentially, it makes `fooEvent.toString()` that much more detailed.

I further suspect that "fully self-contained event objects allow much easier debugging" is a strong reason for the historical double-encoding.